# Creating Delegation token - can't create a SecurityTokenService

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, adfs2.0

I'm trying to build a system working with ADFS and claims. At the moment, this is just a "toy" implementation.

I've built a very simple MVC web application, set it up using the "Identity and Access..." wizard in Visual Studio to talk to an ADFS 2.0 server, and deployed it to an IIS server. All works fine, and I can examine and list the received claims.

The next step is to build a Web API based REST service (representing back-end services that the MVC application is going to depend on), so I want to pass the credentials across to that back-end server so that it can make suitable authorization decisions.

So the first step is for me to create the delegation token (and I'll then, hopefully, work out what to do with it in terms of the `HttpClient` class to make the rest call). I've got this:

```
//We need to take the bootstrap token and create an appropriate ActAs token
var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
{
    AppliesTo = new EndpointReference("https://other-iis.example.com/Rest"),
    RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
    KeyType = KeyTypes.Symmetric,
    ActAs = new SecurityTokenElement(((BootstrapContext)((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).BootstrapContext).SecurityToken)
};

var sts = new SecurityTokenService(); //This line isn't valid
var resp = sts.Issue(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal, rst);
```

But, the issue is that `SecurityTokenService` is abstract. I can't find any types derived from this class in either `System.IdentityModel` nor `System.IdentityModel.Services`, and the above doesn't include any reference to the ADFS server which I'll obviously need to provide at some point.

Of course, I may be going down completely the wrong route also, or am just hitting a minor stumbling block and not seeing a much larger one looming in the distance, so any advice on that would be appreciated also.

---

I've looked at, for example, [Identity Delegation Scenario](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517269.aspx), but that uses `CreateChannelActingAs`, which I don't think is going to work when I'm talking to a rest service (or will it?), and also doesn't seem to apply to .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am requesting tokens from an ADFS 2.0 for caching and looking at the DisplayToken. Maybe this can help you get started.

Here is what I can up with:

```
    public SecurityToken GetToken(out RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to STS...");

        WSTrustChannelFactory factory = null;

        try
        {
            if (_useCredentials)
            {
                // use a UserName Trust Binding for username authentication
                factory =
                    new WSTrustChannelFactory(
                        new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
                        "https://<adfs>/adfs/services/trust/13/UsernameMixed");

                factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;

                // Username and Password here...
                factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
                factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";
            }
            else
            {
                // Windows authentication over transport security
                factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
                    new WindowsWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.Transport),
                    "https://<adfs>/adfs/services/trust/13/windowstransport") { TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13 };
            }

            var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
                          {
                              RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
                              AppliesTo = SvcEndpoint,
                              KeyType = KeyTypes.Symmetric,
                              RequestDisplayToken = true
                          };

            Console.WriteLine("Creating channel for STS...");

            IWSTrustChannelContract channel = factory.CreateChannel();

             Console.WriteLine("Requesting token from " + StsEndpoint.Uri);
             SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst, out rstr);
             Console.WriteLine("Received token from " + StsEndpoint.Uri);

            return token;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (factory != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    factory.Close();
                }
                catch (CommunicationObjectFaultedException)
                {
                    factory.Abort();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You might have to acivate the UsernameMixed Endpoint in your ADFS 2.0 if you want to use it and don't forget to restart the service afterwards!

Answer (score 1):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.securitytokenservice.securitytokenservice.aspx)

To create an STS you must derive from the SecurityTokenService class. In your custom class you must, at a minimum, override the GetScope and GetOutputClaimsIdentity methods.

Comment: I don't want to implement an STS - I want to talk to the ADFS one and get it to issue a delegation token - I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much this will help you, but You're not supposed to create a SecurityTokenService. You are not creating a new token here, and your aplication is not supposed to act as the STS - this is what the AD FS is for.

Your application should only delegate the token received from the AD FS to the service (the concept is described in the link from msdn you provided in your question)

Im guessing theres a good chance the web api will suppor this as well, as its built upon wcf, and from the http point of view - theres no reason it wont support a ws-federation/saml 2 tokens.

EDIT:
[This](http://www.microsoft.com/sv-se/showcase/details.aspx?uuid=ffc61019-9756-4175-adf4-7bdbc6dee400) video (starting at 35:00+-) shows a way, i think, to implement what youre looking for, with ws-federation saml token. im guessing its also possible with a saml2 token

Comment: I kind of got that I don't want to create one myself - but I want to send a request to ADFS for the delegation token - Ideally I'm looking for something like `var sts = new SomeStsObject(adfsEndpointAddress); var tokan = sts.Issue(rst);`, but haven't found this yet.

Comment: Thats not how it supposed to work, if i understand it correctly; You're not supposed to send ad fs requests for delegation. You're supposed to authenticate against it and receive a token, as you'd do in a usual flow. Then, you delegate the received token to the next consumer, assuming he trusts it. You're not supposed to have any line of code doing something as sts.Issue.. BTW, check out [this link](http://leastprivilege.com/). i didnt read all of it, but it seems hes workign on very similar issues.

Comment: What I'm attempting is something like [Identity Delegation with ADFS 2.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-identity-delegation-step-by-step-guide(v=ws.10).aspx), but my back-end service is REST, not WCF, so I can't use `CreateChannelActingAs`, or any of the other WCF features.